# is it possible to run CLI(command line interface) commands through C# code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, c#-4.0

Upload file to Bucket

syn: aws s3 cp [FilePath\FileName] s3://[BucketName]

am excecuted above command by cmd for upload file to S3 Bucket. now i need how to upload file to s3 bucket using c# code. is it possible.?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS offers [SDK for C#](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/), which you must ideally use for such things. Even though you could do what you're asking for using CLI within C#, your work becomes un-necessary complex. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) for how to run commands within C#.